# Analysis error, but compilation successful

Tags: intellij-idea

My compilation (gradle compileJava is successful). Even Build->Make Project does not show any errors. However there is one Java file, which is showing an Analysis error 1 Error found and I get the below error in the balloon message.

```
Ambiguous method call. Both 

apply(SpringSocialConfigurer) in AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder and 
apply(SpringSocialConfigurer) in AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder match
```

My IntelliJ version and other details below

```
IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) IC-144.4199.23
Build #IC-144.4199, built on February 19, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b132 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Comment: Without us being able to compile the same code you are, it's tough for us to say what could be causing it.  However, there are some things you can do - get rid of any residual compiled classes and try rebuilding from scratch.  Use Gradle first, then use IntelliJ to compile to see if you can isolate the issue to be one between IntelliJ and your code or Gradle, IntelliJ, and your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Upgrading to newest version of IDEA solved the problem.

I have now Idea Community Edition, build: IC-145.597.3, and this is fixed.

Comment: I did raise a ticket with IntelliJ folks. Upgrading solved my issue as well